# How to instruct Angular CLI to not manipulate LESS url() at build time?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass, less

We have an Angular 11 application, which needs to be served from a CDN (we build once and deploy to multiple environments and each environment has it's own CDNs). We use LESS for writing our styles.

So, to fetch lazy chunks and assets we set the `__webpack_public_path__` in the following manner (we cannot set `--deploy-url` at build time as it needs to be dynamic), this is the first thing that we import in `main.ts` as per [webpack public path](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) docs.

```
declare let __webpack_public_path__: string;
__webpack_public_path__ = `${(window as any).config.assetUrl}/angular/dist/`;
```

This seems to be working fine for loading lazy chunks and images in templates for e.g. `<img src="../../../images/img.png" />`. But, this does not work for CSS (in our case LESS) `url()`s. For example, the `background: url(../../../images/img.png)` and `background-image: url(../../../images/img.png)` get resolved to `background: url(images/img.png)` and `background-image: url(images/img.png)` at build time (unless you provide `--deploy-url`, which we can't do as it needs to be dynamic).

So, the question is, is there a way to provide `lessOtions` => `rewriteUrls: "local"` to angular-cli? or instruct angular not to resolve relative urls? Or any other way to prepend `__webpack_public_path__` to these background images?

My following custom webpack config seems to do nothing:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./src/main.ts"
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/i,
                exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",
                        options: {
                            lessOptions: {
                                rewriteUrls: "local",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's our folder structure:

```
--root
  |--angular
    |--dist                       // Build artifacts are here
      |--main.js                  // background images urls resolve to "images/img.png"
      |--images
        |--img.png
    |--src
      |--main.ts
      |--app
        |--app.component.ts 
        |--app.component.less     // Assume background/background-image are here
  |--images
    |--img.png                    // This is the image referred in background/background-image urls
```

We are fine with images not being copied to the `dist` folder during build (if that can be achieved), we ship our `images` folder to our CDNs anyways.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I had to implement a custom solution for this to work. I removed all the stylesUrl from my components and created a registration less file for each module, where I just import all the less files for each component of the module. then I instructed Angular CLI to compile these registration files separately as external styles (this can be done from within angular.json architect => build => options => styles). Once this is done you could build a framework to inject these styles as link (has to be link tags otherwise your CSS urls won't resolve correctly) tags when ever the respective modules load.

Comment: Out of interest, why does each environment deployment need a separate CDN url? I also work with deployments to multiple environments, but the JS/html/css/assets are on one CDN

Comment: @Drenai That is because we can have different build versions deployed to each environment (so not all environments will be running on the same build version). Plus if your code is dependent on environment variables/files, having just a single CDN for all environments makes it difficult for your code to figure out what environment it is currently running in. So, it is cleaner to have CDN per environment so that no two or more environments are coupled with each other thus, isolating the infrastructure of each environment.